# "link: error LNK1104: can not open file 'ifconsol.lib'" ifort

Tags: windows, fortran, linker-errors, intel-fortran

"link: error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ifconsol.lib'" that appears when compiling with ifort. Additionally, the .exe file is not generated. The bin folder is already in the path. I am using Windows 11.

"I have tried to put the location of ifconsol.lib in ifort and I hope that when I compile, it will generate the .exe file."

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask] together with [mcve]. We really need the exact details of what you are doing and of your software configuration.

Comment: When you say "the bin folder is already in the path" that suggests to me that you are starting from a bare Windows command prompt and have not run the Intel-provided script to establish the full compile environment.  Assuming you have the current Intel oneAPI compiler, type `call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\setvars.bat" intel64` to do that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.